# How to translate "from nothing to existence" preferably keeping ambiguity

Tags: motto, ambiguity

What's a possible Latin motto meaning roughly "from nothing to existence/reality/something"? I'd like it to be ambiguous if possible, preferably implying "(something) comes into being from nothing" and "from nothingness (as a gift/message) to reality/existence" and "(a path or road) from nothingness to existence" at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Persius (Satire III, 83-84) wrote:

> De nihilo nihilum, in nihilum nil posse reverti.
>
> "Nothing comes from nothing, nothing can return to nothing."

In Latin double negations are fairly frequent and almost always used to express a positive. So one way to say what you want is ***De nihilo non nihilum***, literally "From nothing not nothing". Pretty ambiguous, and I personally prefer this to *De nihilo aliquid* for your purpose.

Inspired by the Catholic concept of *creatio ex nihilo*, another possibility I've thought of is ***Substantia ex nihilo***: *substantia* has many meanings, among which "existence, life" - e.g. *habeo substantiam* means "I exist". Since one may tend to think of "substance, essence" rather than "existence", this is probably most ambiguous. *Ex nihilo* means again "from nothing, from zero".